# numlockLed is enabled but numpads are not working

Tags: linux, xorg, keyboard

I have put the following code to enable Numlock at boot time.

```
#!/bin/bash
for t in /dev/tty[0-9]*; do setleds -D +num <$t; done
```

in start up script.

it is working fine on OS level. but after the Xorg runs, i can  see only the NumlockLed is enabled, but Numpad keys are not working.

I am using Redhat Linux :

- kernel: 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64.
- Xorg version: X.Org X Server 1.13.0

How to enable Numpad keys under Linux Console/Xorg?

Comment: This post for Ubuntu but can help maybe: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock

Comment: Hi Alpertek, Thanks for sharing the link, but I do not have GUI settings like Ubuntu.where i can change the keyboard setting. I have to give some code fix ( script ) to work it correctly.